# PHP Library similar to GD

Tags: php

Im looking for a PHP library similar to the PHP GD library though having simplified classes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the complexity you like to avoid? GD is (mostly) straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Though it would be better if we have something much simpler.

Comment: ImageMagick can be fantastic, but I would hardly describe it as having simplified classes relative to GD like the OP describes. It is generally seen as a 'heavier' tool than GD. However, if you're doing something that ImageMagick supports directly and GD does not, your code will be more concise (and often achieve better results) with ImageMagick. If your goal is truly a simpler or lighter-weight package, look into libvips. It is minimal but has greatly increased performance and reduced memory demands.

Answer (score 7):

GD is only one library for image processing. PHP also has other library extensions:

- [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.
- [Gmagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) a php extension to create, modify and obtain meta information of images using the GraphicsMagick API.
- [Cairo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.cairo.php) a native PHP extension to create and modify graphics using the Cairo Graphics Library.
- [Exif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) With the exif extension you are able to work with image meta data.

Here is comparison: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/comparision_of_php_image_libraries.html

Comment: Wow thanks, if I get the chance I shall try these. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper library like [wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/), which simplifies the interface to GD.

Answer (score 0):

There is another project that aims to simplify GD called [PHP Image Magician](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com) that I'd recommend.